# click on a button using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, test-plan

I am testing a site using `JMeter`. For `form` submission I am using `HTTP Request Sampler` of `JMeter`.Its working fine. But I wanted to know that, is it possible to click `submit buttons` of `html form`s and receive responses using `JMeter`(exactly what we can do using browsers)?

Answer (score 0):

No, You can not simulate events like button click using JMeter. JMEter can record web HTTP request-response and simulate it for a number of times.

You can use [Selenium IDE](https://www.udemy.com/blog/selenium-ide-tutorial/) to record and test user interactions on your web page.